# Which tokenizer and filters to use

Tags: solr, sunspot

**Document With Text** -

`ITA NO. 174 OF 2000 (CIVIL MISC. WRIT PETITION (TAX) NO. 223 OF 2000)`

**Search Text -**

`CIVIL MISC. WRIT PETITION (TAX) NO. 223 OF 2000` (Doesn't give document shown above)

**Tokenizer used -**

`<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s,\.;]+"/>`

While ,
**Queries that give correct result are**

`(CIVIL MISC. WRIT PETITION (TAX) NO. 223 OF 2000)` and

`ITA NO. 174 OF 2000 (CIVIL MISC. WRIT PETITION (TAX) NO. 223 OF 2000)`

**Searched fields -**

`exact` and

`ngram`

I **need the parenthesis to be indexed and be able to be searched** as the contain important information (this works)
But searching just the text without brackets doesn't give the desired result

**What doesn't work -**

Replacing the parenthesis (Affects results relevancy e.g. 139(1) become 1391)

**field type text**

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s,\.;]+"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s,\.;]+"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**field type ngram**

```
<fieldType name="text_ngram" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <!-- <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[\d+\(\)]" replacement=""/> -->
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: could you rephrase the question please. It is quite hard to follow, especially about the part that failed.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch done, please check the question again

Comment: Are you using just `PatternTokenizer` for analyzing the text, no filters? I tried the same in `Solr Admin UI Analysis tab`. All the tokens generated from the query are matching expect `CIVIL` term. because in the source it index as `(CIVIL`.

Comment: @abhishekbafna that's what the problem is `(civil` does not come under edge ngram as well while searching for `civil`
i have used `StandardFilterFactory,LowerCaseFilterFactory,CommonGramsFilterFactory,SynonymFilterFactory,StopFilterFactory,HTMLStripCharFilterFactory` sequentially

Comment: Can you provide the fieldType definition of the field from `schema.xml` which you are indexing. So it would be easy to analyze the problem properly.

Comment: @abhishekbafna added please check

Comment: There is one issue with your `fieldType text` definition. You have put `HTMLStripCharFilterFactory` in the filter chain. This is a `charFilter`, it cannot be chained with filters. The input of `HTMLStripCharFilterFactory` is non-tokenized data. Check the [example](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory).

Comment: @abhishekbafna that said the porter stem filter factory won't work right ?

Comment: It will work. Because it is a filter and input for a filter is `token`, which will be the output of `StopwprdFilter`.

Comment: @abhishekbafna so whats your solution for the above problem then ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88785/discussion-between-abhishek-bafna-and-neo-xx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the pattern in your PatternTokenizerFactory

with this `"/[^a-zA-Z ]/"` or modify the one you have addeding "()" into your expression.

It will remove the `"(" and ")"` from the index and would ease your search.

Going with the your requirement, you can have same field twice in the document with two different fieldType.

One field type will not have the patterfilter factory wherein it will index the text with "()".

other field type will have the patternFilter factory where it will skip the "()" while indexing ..

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: i want "(" and ")" to be indexed and searchable

Comment: here the important thing is getting the result ...it does not matter what you index...if you dont index with "(" and someone is trying to search with "("..you can skip the "(" in the query analyser as well... as you have skiped the while indexing...but as you are storing the same...you will get the exact text in the result...